# Friends and close friends: are two tags necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

This site currently has a [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) tag and a [close-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-friends) tag. Yes, close friends is slightly different from friends. But tags exist to help people find questions. Are there really a lot of people who want to answer questions about close friends but not friends? Personally, if I was interested in answering questions about friendships, I wouldn't care that much about differentiating between the two.

Comment: I've approved your suggested edits, but I don't agree with your assertion that you have community consensus on this yet. 1-3 vote is not consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. I think a more productive way to set things up is [acquaintances](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquaintances) and [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends).

Answer (score 1):

I would really differentiate between [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) and [close-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-friends).

The way you handle things basically different between who you call [friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends), [close-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-friends), and [acquaintances](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquaintances). You can be more direct and open to close friends than to just friends.

---

A perfect example:

> [What is the politest way to tell someone their breath smells?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/471/what-is-the-politest-way-to-tell-someone-their-breath-smells)
>
> #### To close friends
>
> Move closer, and hint that their breath smells without drawing others' attention to it.
>
> #### To not-so-close friends
>
> Probably stand a little further away, and hope they sense why I did that.
>
> #### To coworkers
>
> Depends on how friendly we are. Refer the abovementioned.
>
> #### To siblings
>
> No limit on what I'd say; but not in public though. No formalities.
>
> #### To strangers
>
> Don't mention it. I'd do what I came to do, and move away.

Comment: Again, tags are supposed to help people find questions to answer. They aren't supposed to communicate all of the details in a question. Communicating crucial but small details, like if the friend is a close friend, is the job of the text of the question itself.

Comment: And even though you may categorise the people you know into those categories, there's no reason to think anyone else would use identical categories, or that they'd understand the category labels exactly how you do.